# converting 2d cad image target file into 3d model in unity and vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, autocad

is there any way for unity and vuforia to generate auto 3d model from 2d floorplan of auto cad,it means app detect lines for example and generate 3d plane for walls and other things...
https://floorplancreator.net/plan/demo
look at this,but i dont want to design my 2d plans system,i want to use auto cad printed files,
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXBNK.png)
 i want to app detect some elements and turn it to simple 3d models.